# "Quand" in the sense of "si"

Tags: conjonctions, conditionnel, concordance-des-temps, conditions

In [Matthew 26:35 in the Louis Segond translation](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthieu%2026%3A35&version=LSG), Peter tells Jesus this:

> Quand il me faudrait mourir avec toi, je ne te renierai pas.

I have two questions about this usage, in addition to my standard "Hey, I found this in my outdated Bible translation; do people still say it?"

First: What are the contexts in which can *quand* replace *si* ? I notice that the English translators tends to render it "*even* if", which appears to be in line with [κἄν, the Greek word used](http://biblehub.com/greek/2579.htm). Could it be related to this intensification?

Second: What is going on with the tenses? I would expect a sequence like the following for a typical hypothetical:

> (Même) s'il me fallait mourir avec toi, je ne te renierais pas.

I could understand trading *fallait* for *faudrait*, the same way English can vary "Even if I had to do X someday" and "Even if I'd have to do X someday", but even then, I'm not sure why the imperfect wouldn't suffice to convey that it's hypothetical. Worse, though, is the jump not to conditional but to...  *future*? That makes me think that *faudrait* is somehow counterintuitively supposing a *more* real scenario than *fallait* instead of a *less* real one...

J'espère que quelqu'un pourra me remettre sur le bon chemin !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence form is almost no more used. ***Quand*** is equivalent here to the literary and formal ***quand bien même***.

> Quand bien même il me faudrait mourir avec toi, je ne te renierai pas.

It needs to be followed by the conditional.

On the other hand, ***si*** is always followed by the indicative:

> Même s'il me fallait mourir avec toi, je ne te renierai pas.
>
> Même s'il fallait que je meure avec toi, je ne te renierai pas.

Logically, the conditional would have been expected too here (*même s'il (me) <s>faudrait</s>*), but the grammarians explanation is that ***si*** is already expressing a condition so using the conditional would be redundant.

References:

- http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-quand-indicatif-subjonctif-ou-conditionnel-quel-mode-choisir-79902939.html
- http://www.academie-francaise.fr/catherine-b-france
- http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/tag/quand+bien+m%C3%AAme
- http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-meme-si-indicatif-subjonctif-ou-conditionnel-quel-mode-choisir-79718643.html
- http://bescherelle.ca/conditionnel/

Comment: Merci. What still puzzles me is why the conditional is followed by the indicative (faudrait → renierai).

Comment: I was focused on the first part and overlook the second one which I copy/pasted without paying attention. I believe both moods are possible. The conditional is the natural choice as the clause is part of an hypothesis but the indicative means it's a certainty, a commitment, i.e. whatever the case, (s)he wont deny the other person.

Comment: Although I can't propose a source where to check it, I want to point out that, as a French native, the indicative following the conditional hardly hurts me.